# How to connect Behringer mixer to Macbook Pro?

Tags: mixer, usb, mac, behringer, rca

I have [this mixer](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B000J5SYPY/ref=pd_cp_267_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=KV062RG20ZXYZBM4ZDH8); I'd like to connect a guitar to the mixer and hook up the mixer to my Macbook Pro. I was thinking of connecting the 6.3mm "Main Out" jacks on the mixer to the 3.5mm headphone jack on the MBP - except the headphone jack won't accept audio in.

I've heard you can get a USB cable to connect the mixer to the Mac... but I'm confused about how best to do this. Do I need a USB cable to RCA, and then RCA to 6.3mm? Or is there a simpler way? Any recommended cables would be really helpful!

Comment: While there are mixers in the Xenyx series that feature an USB output, the specified one doesn't.

You need an interface to record with that mixer in a digital manner. Some usb audio interfaces take the form of a cable, but are usually low quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mixer doesnt support usb connectivity,  youll need a usb interface for that. 
After you get a usb interface you can route your mac to output the channels from your usb interface outputs and then just connect them to your mixer. 
Until then you can simply connect your minijack to your mixers input..

Answer (score 1):

Behringer make several small and simple USB audio interfaces like their U-Control series. And versions with more features like the U-Phoria series, etc.  Of course there are many other makers of similar USB audio interfaces as small as a thumb drive.  There are few actual performance differences between these products as most of them typically use the same internal chip for the audio ADC and USB interface.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll have any luck using the macbook headphone jack. Even though they do accept input via one channel on the TRRS port, analog signal sent to that port will be expected at mic level (your mixer's outputs are line level).

An external USB audio interface is absolutely required to use the mixer, as frcake says in their answer.